How to enable my HP Scanner in Ubuntu 24.04?
I'm in Ubuntu 24.04 I have a Hp laserjet MFP M139-M142 I've already printed. All fine. I try to install the scanner via HP toolbox
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.23.12)HP Device Manager ver. 15.0 Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details. warning: Reportlab not installed. Fax coverpages disabled. warning: Please install version 2.0+ of Reportlab for coverpage support. QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
(xsane:5845): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:54:29.325: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "hcengine", Gtk-Message: 16:54:29.326: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

when i give the order to download the plugin needed, i get after few seconds a msg "Python3 is not responding

Turn your printer on and open Document Scanner.
If not already selected, use the drop-down menu to select eSCL HP Color Laserjet MFP....

As helpfully pointed out by @Archisman Panigrahi while some HP printers/scanners work out of the box without hplip, some do not (thankfully, mine did) but in case that is an issue you can install hplip from the official repositories as follows:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install hplip

It is not advised to download random drivers/plugins from the web.
